# Windows Vista UAC displays the code signed application name incorrectly

Tags: windows, windows-vista, code-signing

I code signed my Installer/Uninstaller.exe using the below code:

```
signtool sign  /f "mycert.pfx"   /p Westell1  /t   http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll "Installer.exe"
```

After the code sign, when I tried to run the Installer.exe on Windows Vista 32/64 bit systems, the UAC screen not displaying the application name correctly ("Installer.exe"). It  displays the application name as  "**Insf3e3.tmp**".

Thanks in advance for the  help

Answer (score 1):

The text that UAC displays isn't the filename, it's the `FileDescription` field from the version resource in your executable.

If you're building Installer.exe yourself, you need to add a suitable version resource in your .rc file:

```
VS_VERSION_INFO VERSIONINFO
...
            VALUE "FileDescription", "My Application"
```

If Installer.exe comes from an install builder, you need to look up how to set that string when you build your installer.  For example, with InnoSetup you would say:

```
[Setup]
VersionInfoDescription=My Application
```

Comment: thanks RichieHindle, we are building the installer, I will check this.

Comment: we are using Bitrock installer. while doing the code signing need to pass an argument -d along with the code sign command to display the application name.